# trouble centering active slide in jcarousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I have the slide show working exactly how I would like, except:

To center the active thumbnail, you have to click on it twice, I would like it so that it only takes one click.

The first 3 thumbnails, and last 3 thumbnails do not center, which is how I want it to work. I just want it so if the user clicks once on any thumbnail in-between those, it will center that thumbnail.

If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears, this has been driving me crazy.

You can find a demo at: http://brettjankord.com/standards/slideshows/jslideshow-test2.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, the trouble seems to be with the `onBefore` call, which `.triggers` the `image-loaded`.

I changed the `initCallbackFunction` to this:

```
function initCallbackFunction(carousel) {
    $('.jcarousel-item').click( function() {
         var idx = $('#mycarousel li a.activeSlide').data('index');
         carousel.scroll( idx-2 );
    });  
};
```

And removed the `$('#advanced-slideshow').trigger('image-loaded')`, and now it seems to work fine.

Fix shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xpc4c/show